Why does this function return a pointer instead of pointer's value in C language?
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct 
{
    int *array;  
    int size;     
}Array; 

Array array_create(int init_size);
int* array_at(Array *,int index);
void array_free(Array *);


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    Array a =array_create(100);
    *array_at(&a,0)=10;
    printf("%d\n",*array_at(&a,0));
    array_free(&a);
    return 0;
}


Array array_create(int init_size){
    Array a;     
    a.size = init_size;
    a.array=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*a.size);
    return a;
}

void array_free(Array *a)
{
    free(a->array); 
    a->array=NULL;
    a->size=0;
}


int* array_at(Array *a,int index)
{
    return &(a->array[index]);
}

Why did this C language code not report an error or warning? Shouldn't function array_at only return the value of pointer? Why array_at(&a,0)  is the pointer itself，not the value of the pointer? Why is *array_at(&a,0)   even an lvalue that can be assigned?
Because codes like
#include <stdio.h>

int new(int);

int main(){

    int a=3;
    new(a)=4;
    printf("%d\n",new(a));

}

int new(int i){
    i+=3;
    return i;
}

won't run sucessfully. I think it's because new(a) is just a value of the int variable i and it can't be lvalue, so I really don't understand why the above code can run successfully

It returns a pointer so you can dereference it to update the array element.

if it returned a value, you would have the same problem as in the second program, you can't update it.

@Barmar So the reason it returns the pointer itself is not because of the function header, but because of the array in the function body?

I was answering why the function needs to return a pointer in the first place.


Why did this C language code not report an error or warning?

Because the code is not erroneous or particularly dubious.

Shouldn't function array_at only return the value of pointer?

Functions return values.  Sometimes, as in your case, those values have pointer type.  But function call expressions are not lvalues, so the return value is all there is -- there is no underlying object storing it.  I think that's what you mean by "only return the value of pointer", so yes.

Why array_at(&a,0) is the pointer itself，not the value of the pointer?

You seem to be confused. array_at(&a,0) evaluates to a pointer value, but that expression is not an lvalue, meaning that it does designate an object with storage or lifetime.  And it does not need to be for the apparent purpose.

Why is *array_at(&a,0) even an lvalue that can be assigned?

Because that's what the unary * operator produces.  Its operand does not need to be an lvalue, and often isn't.  Its result, on the other hand, is an lvalue.
And there is nothing unreasonable about that.  A valid, non-null pointer value identifies an object. An expression in the unary * operator designates the object to which the operand points, just like a variable's name designates the object it names.  Either way, you can read the designated object's value.  Either way, if the object is modifiable at all, you can write the designated object's value.

Oh no, So the main problem is The unary* .I didn't know before that The unary* could convert non lvalues to lvalues, which caused such trouble. I‘m a beginner and I didn't find it on c primer plus. Thank you very much for your detailed explanation


Shouldn't function array_at only return the value of pointer?

The function is declared with return type int *, so it should return an int *, which is a pointer to an int, also called an address.
Its return statement provides the address of an int; return &(a->array[index]); uses & to take the address of a->array[index].

Why array_at(&a,0)  is the pointer itself，not the value of the pointer?

The function returns an int *, which is a value that that points to an int. It is the address of an int.

Why is *array_at(&a,0)   even an lvalue that can be assigned?

The unary * produces an lvalue. Applying it to array_at(&a, 0) produces an lvalue for the int that array_at(&a, 0) returns a pointer to.

First  I need to apologize for not clarifying the concept. When I'm talking about pointers, I'm actually talking about pointer variables; And when I'm talking about the value of the pointer, I'm actually talking about the memory address. The memory address should be the pointer constant and a constant should not be assigned right? And I didn't know before that The unary* could convert non lvalues to lvalues, which caused such trouble. Thank you very much
